# Unable to render the calendar properly for FullCalendar AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, fullcalendar

I am new to AngularJS and have to incorporate an Admin LTE full calendar feature in my webapp. I found an Angular directive for the Arshaw  FullCalendar JQuery plugin. The link to the directive is here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Although I am able to display the calendar, I am not able to get the previous, today and next feature working for the calendar. This help to toggle between the months of the calendar. I know this feature is inside the uiConfig but I am not able to understand why this feature doesn't get rendered.

Below is my code. I have included all the files necessary for the plugin but did not show in index.html.

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" resize>
<h1>Calendar Page</h1>
<div class="calendar" ng-model="testevents" config="uiConfig.calendar" ui-calendar="{{uiConfig.calendar}}"></div>
```

**calendarController.js**

```
app.controller("calendarController", ["$scope", "displayCalendar", "dialogs", "$filter", function ($scope, displayCalendar, dialogs, $filter) {

    $scope.$parent.pageTitle = "Displays Reporting Period Start and End Dates";

    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
            eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
            eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
            eventRender: $scope.eventRender
        }
    };


    $scope.form = {};

    $scope.testevents = {
        events: [
            {
                title: 'event1',
                start: '2015-12-12'
            },
            {
                title: 'event2',
                start: '2015-12-11'
            }
            // etc...
        ],
        color: 'yellow',   // an option!
        textcolor: 'black' // an option!
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

looking at the demo code on their github page

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar1" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

I think you would need to change yours to:

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="testevents" calendar="myCalendar1" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar"></div>
```

here is the .html page for their demo

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/demo/index.html

Have you also added the ui-calendar component to the app initialisation?

'var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);'

inside the [] normally you have to inject a third party component so it can be seen by the rest of your controllers.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. But I included this in my app.js where I have all the dependent components added. Here is the code for it.

Comment: `  var app = angular.module('TierIDiversityApp', [ 'ui.calendar',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);`

Any idea what else can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. So after hours and hours of debugging, I figured out what the issue was.
I included fullcalendar.print.css also which was throwing off the styling for fullcalendar.css. 
So an advice peeps, if the buttons are not getting rendered properly u might need to consider checking the CSS and remove fullcalendar.print.css.